# Looking for missing entries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a data table which has 4 columns; Username, Flag, Code and Unique Ref

Now the Unique Ref is like a code which refers to a product. There are a list of these. every user should have access to that unique ref. So if there were 100 unique ref's JSMITH04 would appear 100 times in this table and he would have the unique ref set for each one.

Now lets say there is another called DAVIDMI09 who has only 50 records in the table (which means he does not have all 100 unique ref assigned to him). How can I find which unique ref's he does not have assigned to him? what is the best way in doing this within TSQL?

```
Username    Flag    Code    Unique Ref
JSMITH04    Z   T   12459/43454
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you have a separate table for each user? Something seems amiss with the database design.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Do you have a table which stores product codes which are named [unique ref]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the ones that user does not have you can use EXCEPT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Unique Ref]
FROM TABLE_NAME
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT [Unique Ref]
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE USERNAME == 'DAVIDMI09'
```

or you can use NOT IN

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Unique Ref]
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE [Unique Ref] NOT IN (
  SELECT [Unique Ref]
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE USERNAME == 'DAVIDMI09'
)
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan! Much appreciated.